# binary using both Python C API version 2 and 3

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

In an open source project[1](http://www.sagemath.org) we have Python/Cython and C/C++ modules mixed with one C++ library using the Python C API. The API changed only a few function's names from 2 to 3. Assume the library is written without those functions. Will it link to Python3 if compiled with Python2, and vice versa? Is this prevented by macros in the API headers?

Having a library binary that may link to both would spare us major packaging hassles.

Comment: The names of some pretty fundamental functions have changed (e.g. module initialization I think) mostly for the purpose of preventing you from doing this.

Comment: The API is relatively stable, the A*B*I is not. So you would need to recompile per Python version. Edit: See the link in @DavidW comment to Antti Haapala's answer below for more explanation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it wouldn't work. Don't try it.

Binary modules are not guaranteed to be binary-portable even say from 3.5 to 3.6. If you're *lucky*, then there is some mechanism that will **prohibit you from doing this insanity**. If however you manage to link the library somehow, there will be some subtle differences that will cause serious bugs, such as the layout of `PyObject` changing and so forth.

The Python interface must be recompiled for the exact Python version. Source compatibility between Python 2 and 3 is a different thing and is relatively easy to achieve.

Comment: For Python >=3.2, there is [a stable API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html) that can be used (but is a bit more restricted that the full API). Obviously that doesn't help with OPs problem, but it would allow you to do 3.5 and 3.6 in one binary module.

Comment: Thanks for the definite answer and @DavidW for the link.