# Is Python C module extension version incompatible?

Tags: python, cython, python-c-api

I compile a python c module extension in Python 3.6. It works well in Python 3.6 environment but does not work in Python 3.7 and 3.8 environments, it gets error `cannot import name 'cygrpc'`.

I wondering is this the expected behavior? If yes, what is the reason it.

Comment: I'm not convinced this should be closed (thus I've voted to reopen) - the answer is unambiguous enough that any further details in the question would really be a distraction. I'm slightly surprised that it isn't a duplicate but I can't find a good one ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322187/binary-using-both-python-c-api-version-2-and-3/44324092#44324092) is the closest I can find)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how the extension is compiled and what Python C API interfaces it uses. But yes, **C extensions generally have to be compiled to target a specific version of Python**. In absence of knowledge of how the extension module is created, I would assume it needs to be recompiled.

Usually, the Python C API changes every release. If that change breaks something in your extension, naturally, you'll have to update your extension for the new API interfaces. However, even if your changes are *source-compatible* (no source code changes are needed to support the new Python version) it does not mean that the compiled binaries are necessarily compatible. This is where the *Binary* interface (ABI) comes into play.

See also: [Stable Application Binary Interface](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html) which describes the reason behind this:

> The reason is primarily the evolution of struct definitions, where addition of a new field, or changing the type of a field, might not break the API, but can break the ABI. As a consequence, extension modules need to be recompiled for every Python release [...]

There is also a mention of a limited case in which binaries are compatible across versions:

> Since Python 3.2, a subset of the API has been declared to guarantee a stable ABI. Extension modules wishing to use this API (called “limited API”) need to define Py_LIMITED_API. A number of interpreter details then become hidden from the extension module; in return, a module is built that works on any 3.x version (x>=2) without recompilation.

So, if you only use parts of the stable API and define `Py_LIMITED_API`, then the compiled module may be compatible across Python versions without recompilation.