# src/greenlet/greenlet.h:42:5: error: unknown type name ‘CFrame’

Tags: python

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

```
            gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/jm/pycharm_projects/circus/venv_3_11_dev/include -I/home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11 -c src/greenlet/greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/src/greenlet/greenlet.o
            In file included from src/greenlet/greenlet.c:11:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.h:42:5: error: unknown type name ‘CFrame’
               42 |     CFrame* cframe;
                  |     ^~~~~~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘green_clear_exc’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:173:17: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
              173 |     g->exc_state.exc_type = NULL;
                  |                 ^
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:175:17: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
              175 |     g->exc_state.exc_traceback = NULL;
                  |                 ^
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘g_switchstack’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:528:44: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘recursion_depth’; did you mean ‘recursion_limit’?
              528 |         current->recursion_depth = tstate->recursion_depth;
                  |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  |                                            recursion_limit
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:529:38: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘frame’; did you mean ‘cframe’?
              529 |         current->top_frame = tstate->frame;
                  |                                      ^~~~~
                  |                                      cframe
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:552:25: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘_PyCFrame *’ {aka ‘struct _PyCFrame *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
              552 |         current->cframe = tstate->cframe;
                  |                         ^
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:577:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘recursion_depth’; did you mean ‘recursion_limit’?
              577 |         tstate->recursion_depth = target->recursion_depth;
                  |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  |                 recursion_limit
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:578:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘frame’; did you mean ‘cframe’?
              578 |         tstate->frame = target->top_frame;
                  |                 ^~~~~
                  |                 cframe
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:601:24: warning: assignment to ‘_PyCFrame *’ {aka ‘struct _PyCFrame *’} from incompatible pointer type ‘int *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
              601 |         tstate->cframe = target->cframe;
                  |                        ^
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘g_initialstub’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:813:5: error: unknown type name ‘CFrame’
              813 |     CFrame trace_info;
                  |     ^~~~~~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:857:18: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘_PyCFrame’ {aka ‘struct _PyCFrame’}
              857 |     trace_info = *PyThreadState_GET()->cframe;
                  |                  ^
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:864:17: error: request for member ‘previous’ in something not a structure or union
              864 |     self->cframe->previous = &PyThreadState_GET()->root_cframe;
                  |                 ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:878:50: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘recursion_depth’; did you mean ‘recursion_limit’?
              878 |     self->recursion_depth = PyThreadState_GET()->recursion_depth;
                  |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  |                                                  recursion_limit
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘green_new’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1018:34: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘_PyCFrame *’ {aka ‘struct _PyCFrame *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             1018 |         ((PyGreenlet*)o)->cframe = &PyThreadState_GET()->root_cframe;
                  |                                  ^
            In file included from /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/Python.h:45,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.h:8,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.c:11:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘green_traverse’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1124:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
             1124 |     Py_VISIT(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/objimpl.h:199:13: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
              199 |         if (op) {                                                       \
                  |             ^~
            In file included from /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/Python.h:44,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.h:8,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.c:11:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1124:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
             1124 |     Py_VISIT(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:107:41: note: in definition of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
              107 | #define _PyObject_CAST(op) ((PyObject*)(op))
                  |                                         ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1124:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
             1124 |     Py_VISIT(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |     ^~~~~~~~
            In file included from /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/Python.h:45,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.h:8,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.c:11:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1126:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
             1126 |     Py_VISIT(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/objimpl.h:199:13: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
              199 |         if (op) {                                                       \
                  |             ^~
            In file included from /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/Python.h:44,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.h:8,
                             from src/greenlet/greenlet.c:11:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1126:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
             1126 |     Py_VISIT(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:107:41: note: in definition of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
              107 | #define _PyObject_CAST(op) ((PyObject*)(op))
                  |                                         ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1126:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
             1126 |     Py_VISIT(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |     ^~~~~~~~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘green_clear’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1162:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
             1162 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:107:41: note: in definition of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
              107 | #define _PyObject_CAST(op) ((PyObject*)(op))
                  |                                         ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1162:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
             1162 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |     ^~~~~~~~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1162:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
             1162 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:561:14: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
              561 |             (op) = NULL;                        \
                  |              ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1164:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
             1164 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:107:41: note: in definition of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
              107 | #define _PyObject_CAST(op) ((PyObject*)(op))
                  |                                         ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1164:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
             1164 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |     ^~~~~~~~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1164:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
             1164 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:561:14: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
              561 |             (op) = NULL;                        \
                  |              ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘green_dealloc’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1256:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
             1256 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:107:41: note: in definition of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
              107 | #define _PyObject_CAST(op) ((PyObject*)(op))
                  |                                         ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1256:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
             1256 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |     ^~~~~~~~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1256:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
             1256 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_type);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:561:14: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
              561 |             (op) = NULL;                        \
                  |              ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1258:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
             1258 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:107:41: note: in definition of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
              107 | #define _PyObject_CAST(op) ((PyObject*)(op))
                  |                                         ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1258:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
             1258 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |     ^~~~~~~~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1258:29: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
             1258 |     Py_CLEAR(self->exc_state.exc_traceback);
                  |                             ^
            /home/jm/.pyenv/versions/3.11-dev/include/python3.11/object.h:561:14: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
              561 |             (op) = NULL;                        \
                  |              ^~
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c: In function ‘PyGreenlet_New’:
            src/greenlet/greenlet.c:1777:15: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘_PyCFrame *’ {aka ‘struct _PyCFrame *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             1777 |     g->cframe = &PyThreadState_GET()->root_cframe;
                  |               ^
            error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]
```

Version info:

- ubuntu 20.04
- python 3.11-dev

Looks related:

- https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/CFrame

Comment: Quoting from https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/273: "In general, released versions of greenlet may or may not work with Python versions that are newer than the release. It often (but not always) requires a new version of greenlet to support a new version of Python."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Python C module extension version incompatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654772/is-python-c-module-extension-version-incompatible)

Comment: https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet → Ubuntu 20.04, default python3 = 3.8.10 . ...... `cd greenlet/ && python3 setup.py build` : No errors.

Answer (score 2):

To make @jmunsch answer more clear. Check that your pip version is the latest possible. After that, to install a py3.11-compatible greenlet, use:

```bash
$ pip3.11 install greenlet==2.0.0a2
```

Do note this is an [alpha version](https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/303).

I personally ran into this problem while trying to pip install sqlalchemy. The solution for me was to run the above command to install greenlet first before installing sqlalchemy. (pip install sqlalchemy resolves to install the incompatible versions of greenlet).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was an issue between versions:

- https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/295#issuecomment-1078891696

> Versions of greenlet prior to 2.0a2 (released yesterday) do not work with Python 3.11a6.

However it also appears that `2.0.a2` of greenlet was released the day after surfacing the issue.

Thanks @jamadden